# Issue with displaying dropdown menu as a block in responsive navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I am trying to build a responsive navigation bar. Everything seems to be working fine but once the screen is reduced and the button appears, the menu does not display properly when the button is clicked.

The answer is probably very simple but I am just getting started and can't seem to figure it out. I have tried to modify the CSS code to achieve the proper result, meaning that the menu should display in block underneath the button, but nothing I try seems to work.

I included the HTML, CSS and Javascript code that I am using for the navigation bar. Help! Thank you all.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
                    <title>X</title>
                    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
                        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
                        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
                            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                            </head>
                            <body>
                                <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
                                    <nav role="banner">
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <img id="topnavLogo" src="images/logo-navbar-white.png" width="240" height="180">
                                            </a>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a class="page-icon" href="#">Log in</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a class="page-icon" href="#">Sign up</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a class="page-icon" href="#">About</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                                                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </nav>
                                    </div>
                                    <style>
            #topnavLogo{
                float:left;
                color: #fff;
                text-align: left;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-variant: small-caps;
                padding-top:-50px;
                padding-bottom: 15px;
                padding-left: 30px;
                margin:-55px;
            }

            .topnav {
                width: 100%;
                height: 60px;
                background-color: #0008;
                line-height: 60px;
                position: fixed;
                display:inline-block;
              }

            ul li{
                  display:inline;
                  float:right;
              }

              .active {
                background-color: #4CAF50;
                color: white;
              }

              .topnav .icon {
                display: none;
              }

              .page-icon{
                color: #fff;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 5px 5px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 17px;
                margin-right: 30px;
                font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                font-variant: small-caps;
              }

              .page-icon:hover {
                color: #9bc0d3;
              }

              @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
                .topnav li a {display: none;}
                .topnav a.icon {
                  float: right;
                  display: block;
                  padding: 0 1em 0 0;
                  color: #fff;
                  font-size: 1.5em;
                }
                  .topnav a.icon:hover {
                    color: #9bc0d3;
                }
              }

              @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
                .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
                .topnav.responsive a.icon {
                  position: absolute;
                  right: 0;
                  top: 0;
                }

                .topnav.responsive a {
                    float: none;
                    display: block;
                    text-align: left;
                    color: #9bc0d3;  
                }
              }
            </style>
<script>

            function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
                if (x.className === "topnav") {
                  x.className += " responsive";
                } else {
                  x.className = "topnav";
                }
              }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below has the menu appear fullwidth under the header when the small screen menu button is pressed. When on a larger screen it acts as a normal header. I also played around with the logo image which wasn't behaving appropriately.

Let me know if this isn't what you were hoping for.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#topnavLogo {
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  padding-left: 30px;
  max-height: 60px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 25px;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/240x80.png/09f/fff');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
}

.topnav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #0008;
  line-height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
}

.topnav ul {
  margin: 0px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.page-icon {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.page-icon:hover {
  color: #9bc0d3;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    color: #9bc0d3;
  }
  
  .topnav li a {
    display: none;
    margin: 0px;
    float: none;
  }
  
  .topnav.responsive li a {
    display: inherit;
  }
  
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 1em 0 1em;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  
  .topnav a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  
  .topnav a.icon:hover {
    color: #9bc0d3;
  }
  
  .topnav ul {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background: #0008;
    display: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  
  .topnav.responsive ul {
    display: inherit;
  }
  
  nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <nav role="banner">
    <a href="#" id="topnavLogo">

    </a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="page-icon" href="#">Log in</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-icon" href="#">Sign up</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-icon" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, that is exactly what I was hoping for ! I will get to work on the logo. Thank you, Oliver.

Answer (score 0):

You were setting `display: block` and `display: none` to the `<a>` element instead of its wrapper `<li>`.

For your menu to display properly, you need to add these 2 rules:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav ul > li {display: none;}
  .topnav.responsive ul > li {width:100%; display: block;}
}
```

Comment: That does achieve the expected result, although the whole thing appears to float left instead of appear beneath the button. Thank you, Vedran.

Comment: You're welcome.
Indeed, text is on the left side because of `.topnav.responsive a { /* [...] */  text-align: left; }`. Changing `text-alight` to `right` fixes it.